# How to solve an equation that has tanh() in python

Tags: python, equation, nonlinear-functions

I know how to solve an algebraic Equations : x^4-1=0 as below

```
from sympy import solve, symbols
x = symbols('x')
solve(x**4 - 1, x)
```

But I got a problem cuz I have tanh() in my equation today like below:

```
tanh(C1+x*C2) + tanh(C1-x*C2) = C3
```

Where `C1,C2,C3` are pre-specified then how to solve for `x`?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you need a general solver for algebraic equations, or just that specific example.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm new here. I edited my question. Wish it will be more clearly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your question you need just something like

```
from sympy import solve, symbols, tanh
c1 = 1
c2 = 1
c3 = 1
x = symbols('x')
solve(tanh(c1+x*c2)+tanh(c1-x*c2)-c3, x)
```